# updating bean values from controller,multiple inserts on button click

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am new to jsf jpa rest.I was wondering how do set values in beans from the controller beans.

Say suppose once the user registers I want to insert the values to the DB along with date which I generate in the controllerbean.Now how do I set this in the POJO

register.xhtml

```
<h:form id="registerForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" id="register">
                        <h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">Customer
                            Information</h2>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="name" size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your name" value="#{registerController.selected.contactName}">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="company" value="Company:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="company" size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your company" value="#{registerController.selected.company}">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="designation" value="Designation:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="designation"  size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your designation" value="#{registerController.selected.designation}">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email Id:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="email"  size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your email,eg:yourid@domain.com" value="#{registerController.selected.primaryEmailId}" title="eg:www.domain.com OR http://127.0.0.1/domain">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="70"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="phone" value="Contact No:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="phone" size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your contact number" value="#{registerController.selected.contactNo}" title="eg:+919999999999">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="13" maximum="25"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="loginInfo">
                        <h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">Login Information</h2>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label"> 
                                <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Email:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputText id="email"  size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your login email id,eg:yourid@domain.com" value="#{loginController.selected.clientId}">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="70"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputText>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputSecret id="password"  size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your desired password(minimun 6 characters)" value="#{loginController.selected.password}">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputSecret>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <h:outputLabel for="confirm_password" value="Confirm Password:"></h:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td class="field">
                                <h:inputSecret id="confirm_password" size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please confirm your password">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
                                </h:inputSecret>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h:commandButton value="Sign Up" action="">
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

Now my Register and login bean contain getters and setters

login bean

```
       public String getLoginEmail() {
        return loginEMail;
    }

    public void setLoginEmail(String loginEMail) {
        this.loginEMail = loginEMail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Register bean

```
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String ContactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        System.out.println("get....." + company);
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
        System.out.println("set....." + company);
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        System.out.println("get....." + designation);
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
        System.out.println("set....." + primaryDesignation);
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getActiveFlag() {
        return activeFlag;
    }

    public void setActiveFlag(String activeFlag) {
        this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        System.out.println("get create name....." + createdBy);
        createdBy=getPrimaryContactName();
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String primaryContactName) {
        this.createdBy = primaryContactName;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        System.out.println("set....." + createdOn);
    }
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String primaryContactName) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = primaryContactName;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        return lastUpdatedOn;
    }

   public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
       this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }
```

I have two controllers registerController and loginController where I have the business logic.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "registerController")
@SessionScoped
    public String prepareCreate() {
    System.out.println("Inside create");
    current = new Register();
    System.out.println("Inside create current");
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "Signup Success";
}

public String create() {
    try {
        System.out.println("I am inside create");
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("RegisterCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("I am here inside create exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}

public Date generateCurrentTime()
{
    // get current system time yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
            Date convertedDate=null;
            try
            {
            convertedDate=formatter.parse(dateNow);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("date now is:"+dateNow);
            return convertedDate;
}
```

Similarly loginController also contains the same code.
How do I set the convertedDate attribute for createdOn and lastUpdatedOn feilds in the pojo??

I used @ManagedBeanProperty but it dint set the value...

```
@ManagedBeanProperty(value=#{registerController.getgenerateCurrentTime})
  @Column(name = "created_on")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   private Date createdOn;


  @ManagedBeanProperty(value=#{registerController.getgenerateCurrentTime})
  @Column(name = "created_on")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   private Date lastUpdatedOn;
```

Kindly point out where I am goin wrong.I have used @sessionscoped

Also as u can see I have two tables in a form and they are dependent on each other.How do I insert them into database when user clicks on register button...Should I pass the control initially on the button click to controller say setupController and then call register and login controller

Thanks:)

Comment: have you provided method in action of  <h:commandButton value="Sign Up" action=""> ?

Comment: I am asking if I shuld say action="#{setupController.create}" or is there another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:commandButton value="Sign Up" action="">
```

does the submission of the form which leads to storing the values of fields in back bean (if no ajax used)

and providing an action in command button like `action="#{setupController.create}"` will cause the invokation of that method `create` on the submission of the form after the assignment of the fields to the bean.

also you can provide it in action  of form

refer [How to define form action in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715308/how-to-define-form-action-in-jsf)

Comment: I am storing the values in the back bean using value="#{registerController.selected.contactName}".Since I have two controllers should I create one more controller to which I pass the controll and in that controller I call create method of registerController and loginController...

Comment: Also for every user I am adding createdOn feild which stores the date whose logic is in the controller.How do I update the value of this in my back bean??

Comment: the values is stored in backbean only at the time of form submission. not only by providng it as value="#{registerController.selected.contactName}" or you need to provide   <h:inputText id="name" size="20" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your name" value="#{registerController.selected.contactName}">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="50"></f:validateLength><f:ajax/>
                                </h:inputText>

Comment: that means you want two actions when a user register first you want to call createdon and  then create?

Comment: I get that...What I am confused is with how to I call the two controllers on a single button click??

Comment: you can call the createdon method inside the created method

Comment: Yes Hemant...The tables are dependent on each other.I want to insert into both the tables simultaneously

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6881/discussion-between-hemant-metalia-and-newbie)

Answer (score 0):

as the other friends said you need to invoke an action to set the values on the backing bean...you can make a method that is invoked by your button's action , and inside that method yo can call your service to store your data in the DB. cheers