# Spring security LDAP - JSF login not working

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security, ldap

I am trying to develop an app using Spring 3.1.1 with spring security with LDAP authentication. Also, for front-end I will use JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces.

I have configured my LDAP server and navigation rules like so:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
<security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/index.xhtml"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref = "authProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="authProvider" 
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="xxx" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://xxx:389"/> 
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref = "customUserContextMapper"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customUserContextMapper" class="CustomUserDetailsMapper"></bean>
```

I have written a custom UserDetailsMapper which extends LdapUserDetailsMapper because I'm not sure where else to put a "handler" after a login is done:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper{

private static final String ROLE_NORMAL_USER = "Normal User";
private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "Administrator";
@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
        String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {
    UserDetails originalUser = super.mapUserFromContext( ctx, username, authority );


    originalUser.getAuthorities();

    Set<AndaAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(AndaAuthority.class);

    roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);

    for (GrantedAuthority auth : authority) {
        if (ROLE_NORMAL_USER.equalsIgnoreCase(auth.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_USER);
        } else if (ROLE_ADMIN.equalsIgnoreCase(auth.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);
        }
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();

    User newUser = 
            new User( 
            originalUser.getUsername(), 
            originalUser.getPassword() != null? originalUser.getPassword():"", 
            originalUser.isEnabled(), 
            originalUser.isAccountNonExpired(), 
            originalUser.isCredentialsNonExpired(), 
            originalUser.isAccountNonLocked(), 
            roles );

            return newUser;
}
}
```

I have a login.xhtml page that is in the root of WEB-INF and I set is as the welcome page. here is my web.xml:

```
[..]
<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->
  <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
     </param-value>
  </context-param>

[..]

  <!--  Spring security related configs -->
  <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
[..]
```

Below is the login form:

```
<h:form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Username" />
            <h:inputText id="j_username" />
            <h:outputText value="Password" />
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Login</span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

I got the idea for the login page from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715308/how-to-define-form-action-in-jsf). I am not sure how to set the action, be it `j_spring_security_check` or `../j_spring_security_check`. I tried with both and the same result...

**What happens:**
When I open the app in Tomcat, the login page is displayed. After I enter my credentials, I am redirected again to login.xhtml, with only the username filled in. And so on...

The login part was working when I tried it with my config in a sample Spring security LDAP integration application. There, the `mapUserFromContext` method was called every time. Now, the breakpoint is never entered.

Also, in the sample app - the **user.password** was always **null** and the authority list was always empty. Is that normal? Could anyone suggest a better way of overriding the normal login to know where something is broken?

The sample app was working because it was made with JSP maybe and I messed something up with JSF...

**I believe it's a JSF issue from my part but can't figure out why. Also, do you have any idea how to implement a better "login success handler" for this case?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't even understand why this question has been closed without any comments. This is called abusing the power that you have. @AndaP, you cannot post to j_spring_security_check like that ..please refer to [spring-custom-jsf-login-page-always-bad-credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742283/spring-custom-jsf-login-page-always-bad-credentials) on how to use custom JSF page with Spring

Comment: Wow, thank you Ravi! That helped and I finally managed to make it work. I used the LoginController from the tutorial in the link. Too bad you can't enter a real answer...

Comment: I also agree it shouldn't have been closed

Comment: There is an solution to the problem..why it is closed?? I rem the saying'with great power comes great responsibility'