# how can i navigate to an absolute path from a h:commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, commandbutton

I have something like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="test" action="#{bean.action}"/>
```

once the action method is evaluated, I would like to navigate (only in some cases) to an absolute URL.

I know that if the "bean.action" returns a relative path that corresponds to a valid path in context it will go there, but I don't want that.

I want to evaluate the action return and if it is all ok navigate to an absolute URL like "www.anypage.com", something like

```
<a href="www.anypage.com">test</a>
```

but depending on action return and keeping the jsf2 advantages.

Any ideas? Thx a lot

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159358/hcommandbutton-how-to-redirect-to-external-sitejsf-2, an absolute URL is also called an external url.

Comment: `www.anypage.com` is not an absolute URL at all. It does not start with a scheme. When currently in `http://example.com/context/somepage.xhtml`, you'd after clicking that link end up in `http://example.com/context/www.anypage.com` which will likely result in a 404 error.

Comment: I will consider it, thx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just use `ExternalContext.redirect()` in your action method:

```
public String action() {
    doYourProcessing();
    if(/*some condition*/) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(/*absolute path*/);
    } else {
        //return a navigation case outcome or null for a postback
    }
}
```