# Using h:button to generate a button and link to a non-jsf page

Tags: jsf, button

I want to use h:button to navigate to another page in my application, and this is not a jsf page (its a */context/strutsPage.do* page). Unfortunately i only have the outcome attribute in this tag which i understand only accesses jsf pages. How can i still use the button tag (or similar) because i really want to generate a button and not a link? Is there another solution to generate a button?
Thanks
PS i'm using struts and jsf in the same app temporarily in order to migrate gradually to jsf

Comment: You could use `h:commandButton` instead. Perform a POST action and redirect to the external url with the external context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159358/hcommandbutton-how-to-redirect-to-external-sitejsf-2

Answer (score -1):

From what I know `h:button` has `onclick` attribute. You could just make:

```
<h:button onclick="window.location.href='some_page.html'" />
```